# PHPMailer & Mailhog: connection refused, host not known

Tags: connection, phpmailer, mailhog

trying to get Mailhog to run.  i'm running a [Neard](https://neard.io) stack and i haven't used Mailhog before.  the docs are slim for somebody who isn't familiar with email services (*finger pointing at self*).  here's what i have code-wise:

```php
//  create the instance
  $mail = new PHPMailer;
  $mail->isSMTP();  //  i read somwhere that this may require commenting out to work...
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
  $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
  $mail->Host = 'mail';    //  i also tried 'localhost' here... same result
  $mail->Port = 1025;
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Username = EMAILUSERNAME;
  $mail->Password = EMAILPASSWORD;

  $mail->setFrom($from, $senderName);
  $mail->addReplyTo('blorp@blorp.blorp');   //  obviously a placeholder
  $mail->addAddress($to);
  $mail->Subject = $subject;
  $mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents(__DIR__.'\90days.php'));

  //  send the email and check for errors
  if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Mail error: '. $mail->ErrorInfo;
  } else {
    echo 'Message sent Successfully';
  }
```

running it through [Postman](https://www.postman.com/), i get the following error:

```
2020-04-15 01:53:50 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. (0)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mail error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

from what i understand from [this post](http://2020-04-15%2001:53:50%20SMTP%20ERROR:%20Failed%20to%20connect%20to%20server:%20php_network_getaddresses:%20getaddrinfo%20failed:%20No%20such%20host%20is%20known.%20(0)%20SMTP%20connect()%20failed.%20https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting%20Mail%20error:%20SMTP%20connect()%20failed.%20https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting), all i had to do was set the `Host` and `Port` to the settings above and Mailhog would intercept.  but it doesn't work.  so what did i overlook or misconfigure?

Comment: Port 1025 is pretty unusual, so check it's correct. Beyond that, it's likely your hosting provider blocks outbound SMTP.

Comment: right from the Mailhog git page: 
    Configure MailHog, or use the default settings:

    the SMTP server starts on port 1025
    the HTTP server starts on port 8025

Comment: Ok. I didn’t read the bit of the error message that had scrolled out of view: “no such host” suggests that either your Host value is wrong, or your DNS is not working.

Comment: hm. maybe i'll try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.  get back to you on that...

Comment: nope. that didn't work either. shoot. :(

Comment: Since you're using neard, here's [the answer](https://github.com/neard/neard/issues/451)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and I solved removing **SMTPSecure**

`//  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';`

Hope this helps someone else.